# Add Hyperlink Button using CSS to Jquery Loopedslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

So I've spent the last 2 hours banging my head against the wall, for what is probably a simple solutuion(?):

I want to add a Hyperlink button using CSS to each image/div in jquery Loopedslider.

I've used loopedslider a number of times previously, but never needed to add hyperlink buttons. A good example of this would be Amazons webstore homepage: http://webstore.amazon.co.uk/ Where the button is in the lower left corner for each image.

Is this possible with Loopedslider? Christ, does that even make sense?? :-/

Any help would be mucho appreciated! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.yourDiv:after{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    content: "click here!";
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "comic sans", arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Of course you'll need to target the specific divs in the slider with e.g. .slider div{}

And then in js add the click functions.

UPDATE:
Seems like jQuery can't put functionality to :after elements. So my suggestion is that you add the buttons in jQuery instead of css.

This should do it!

```
$("#loopedSlider .slider div").each(function(){
    // of course you'll need to create the class (.myBtnStyling) in your css file...
    var btn = $("<div>")
        .addClass("myBtnStyling")
        .text("Click here!");

    btn.click(function(){
        // click functionality here...
        alert("yay");
    });

    $(this).append(btn);
});
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific re: targeting the Divs and js click functions please? Do I need to re-name each of the .slides div's in order for each to link to a different page? I think all this Christmas cheer has affected my brain cell!? :-/

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I sorted the issue, simply:

<div class="item-one">
<div class="slideBtn"><a href="page.html">READ MORE</a></div>
</div><!---end item-one--->

..and styling the css class accordingly.

Thank you again though tommy.